# Unable to launch Git as non-administrator on Windows 11

Tags: windows, git

I have git installed for months and it worked fine. But today when I tried to launch git from Command Prompt, it says

`error launching git: Access is denied.`

When I run Command Prompt as the administrator and launch git, it works fine.

I got a Windows update this morning and I'm not sure if it is related.

> git version 2.40.1.windows.1
>
> Windows 10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621

Reinstalling git doesn't solve the problem. Then I granted full control permissions of `git.exe` to all users, which doesn't help as well.

Comment: The only other reference to such an error is [this bug entry, which also doesn't seem to have a solution](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/15879). On there a suggestion is some interference by some Anti-Virus software. It's possible that your AV got a signature update and now falsely identifies the `git` binary as being infected/malware.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimSauer, it was the AV blocking ``git`` from running. I turned off McAfee's real time scanning and everything went well.